# Can't get expected JSON from urllib2

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I am trying to interact with the Jira API.  I can get it working using the cURL command below, and I get the JSON I expect, but I need to write a Python script so I figured I should use urllib2 (all of these things are new to me).  THis is as far as I can get:  I am getting an HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type.  I tried including `Content-Type: application/json` in the header, but then I get an HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.  Any thoughts?

```
import urllib2, urllib
import os.path
import cookielib

# curl -c cookie_jar -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username" : "XXXX", "password" : "XXXXXX"}' http://www.host.net/rest/auth/latest/session

COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.lwp'
urlopen=urllib2.urlopen
Request=urllib2.Request
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
if os.path.isfile(COOKIEFILE):
    cj.load(COOKIEFILE)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgr()
url = 'http://www.host.net/rest/auth/latest/session'
user = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXXX'
realm = "http://www.host.net"
password_mgr.add_password(realm, url, user, password)
txheaders =  {
    'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)',} 
    # "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
txdata = urllib.urlencode({"username" : "XXXX", "password" : "XXXXX"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

req = Request(url, txdata, txheaders)
try:
    handle = urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
    print e.read()
```

Comment: With the "content-type: application/json" included, I get:

{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character ('u' (code 117)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6bb8b90b; line: 1, column: 2]"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind--apparently the answer is that the requests library is far, far superior to urllib2.  Took me about ten seconds.

Comment: Please give more details. I Have the same issue. What transformation did you apply to your code to it make work ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really remember the details, only that using requests was much easier and better than urllib2.